# No module named 'datablogger_scraper'

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and following this [tutorial](https://www.data-blogger.com/2016/08/18/scraping-a-website-with-python-scrapy/)

But I keep getting no module named datablogger_scraper.  I have named this in items.py and settings.py as seen below. The name looks correct to me

I thought maybe that it was named incorrectly so I tried this example but changed all the datablogger to datablogger1 but still issue.

Why is it giving me this issue?

Thank you

I get:

```
C:\Users\dac\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\python.exe C:/Users/dac/PycharmProjects/datablogger_scraper/datablogger_scraper/spiders/datablogger.py
C:/Users/dac/PycharmProjects/datablogger_scraper/datablogger_scraper/spiders/datablogger.py:7: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.linkextractor` is deprecated, use `scrapy.linkextractors` instead
  from scrapy.linkextractor import LinkExtractor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dac/PycharmProjects/datablogger_scraper/datablogger_scraper/spiders/datablogger.py", line 9, in <module>
    from datablogger_scraper.items import DatabloggerScraperItem
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datablogger_scraper'
```

This: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datablogger_scraper'`

When I run:

```
scrapy crawl datablogger -o links.csv -t csv




# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractor import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from datablogger_scraper.items import DatabloggerScraperItem


class DatabloggerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    # The name of the spider
    name = "datablogger"

    # The domains that are allowed (links to other domains are skipped)
    allowed_domains = ["data-blogger.com"]

    # The URLs to start with
    start_urls = ["https://www.data-blogger.com/"]

    # This spider has one rule: extract all (unique and canonicalized) links, follow them and parse them using the parse_items method
    rules = [
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                canonicalize=True,
                unique=True
            ),
            follow=True,
            callback="parse_items"
        )
    ]

    # Method which starts the requests by visiting all URLs specified in start_urls
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)

    # Method for parsing items
    def parse_items(self, response):
        # The list of items that are found on the particular page
        items = []
        # Only extract canonicalized and unique links (with respect to the current page)
        links = LinkExtractor(canonicalize=True, unique=True).extract_links(response)
        # Now go through all the found links
        for link in links:
            # Check whether the domain of the URL of the link is allowed; so whether it is in one of the allowed domains
            is_allowed = False
            for allowed_domain in self.allowed_domains:
                if allowed_domain in link.url:
                    is_allowed = True
            # If it is allowed, create a new item and add it to the list of found items
            if is_allowed:
                item = DatabloggerScraperItem()
                item['url_from'] = response.url
                item['url_to'] = link.url
                items.append(item)
        # Return all the found items
        return items
```

Items.py:

```
import scrapy

class DatabloggerScraperItem(scrapy.Item):
    # The source URL
    url_from = scrapy.Field()
    # The destination URL
    url_to = scrapy.Field()
```

Settings:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Scrapy settings for datablogger_scraper project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = 'datablogger_scraper'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['datablogger_scraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'datablogger_scraper.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'datablogger_scraper (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
#DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16

# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
#COOKIES_ENABLED = False

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
#TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
#DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
#   'Accept-Language': 'en',
#}

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'datablogger_scraper.middlewares.DatabloggerScraperSpiderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'datablogger_scraper.middlewares.MyCustomDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable extensions
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
#EXTENSIONS = {
#    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
#}

# Configure item pipelines
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
#ITEM_PIPELINES = {
#    'datablogger_scraper.pipelines.DatabloggerScraperPipeline': 300,
#}

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
#AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
#AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
#AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
#AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
#AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
#HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
#HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
#HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
#HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
#HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'
```

Comment: Code seems fine.  Maybe it is my directory?

Comment: Just to make sure: do you have an `datablogger_scraper` directory (containing a `__init__.py` file)?

Comment: why do you run `spiders/datablogger.py` ? it is spider which is imported by scrapy when you scrapy with `scrapy crawl datablogger -o links.csv -t csv`. You can't run it directly

Comment: and you have to run `scrapy crawl ...` when you are in folder `C:/Users/dac/PycharmProjects/datablogger_scraper/`